# How to activate an interval when a certain position is reached?

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that It calls the var `intervalLeft` and `intervaRight` at the same time. When it is moving right I want the `intervalLeft` not to work & vice versa.
When It reaches `startPosition` 100 it activates the `intervalLeft` and when it reaches `startPosition` 0 it activates `intervalRight` infinite.

```
<div id="moveAnimation" class="block"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var elem = document.getElementById("moveAnimation");
  elem.addEventListener("click", movingImage);

  function movingImage() {
    var startPosition = 0;
    var intervalRight = setInterval(frameRight, 10);
    var intervalLeft = setInterval(frameLeft, 10);

    function frameRight() {
      if (startPosition >= 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalRight);
        frameLeft();
      } else {
        startPosition += 0.5;
        document.getElementById("moveAnimation").style.left = startPosition + "%";
      }
    }

    function frameLeft() {
      if (startPosition <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalRight);
        frameRight();
      } else {
        startPosition -= 2;
        document.getElementById("moveAnimation").style.right = startPosition + "%";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is the exercise:

Below this, you have a div that needs to move left to right using JS for the motion. Make it reach the end in 2 seconds, then return in 5s. Repeat that forever.

Comment: `startPosition -= 2;` is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated your code. Use below

```
<div id="moveAnimation" class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("moveAnimation");
        elem.addEventListener("click", movingImage);



        function movingImage() {
            var startPosition = 0;
            var intervalRight = setInterval(frameRight, 10);
            var rightTimer = true;
            var leftTimer = false;
            var intervalLeft;

            function frameRight() {
                if(!rightTimer){
                    rightTimer = true;
                    intervalRight = setInterval(frameRight,10)
                    return;
                }
                if (startPosition >= 100) {
                    rightTimer = false;
                    clearInterval(intervalRight);
                    frameLeft();

                } else {

                    startPosition += 0.5;
                    document.getElementById("moveAnimation").style.left        =     startPosition + "%";
                }

            }

            function frameLeft() {
                if(!leftTimer){
                    leftTimer = true;
                    intervalLeft = setInterval(frameLeft,10)
                    return;
                }
                if (startPosition <= 0) {
                    leftTimer = false;
                    clearInterval(intervalLeft);
                    frameRight();

                } else {

                    startPosition -= 2;
                      document.getElementById("moveAnimation").style.left = startPosition + "%";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It's not working tough. It makes the div jump straight back to the left (position 0) after it reaches 100. And then it stays there.

Comment: @Jonas.D - Have updated the code. Should work now. Sorry didn't test it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

After testing some more i've found the answer with fewer lines of code.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("moveAnimation");
            elem.addEventListener("click", movingImage);

            function movingImage() {
                var startPosition = 0;
                var intervalRight = setInterval(frameRight, 10); //1 





                function frameRight() {
                    if (startPosition >= 100) {
                        clearInterval(intervalRight);
                        intervalLeft = setInterval(frameLeft, 10);


                    } else {
                        startPosition += 0.5;
                        document.getElementById("moveAnimation").style.left =    startPosition + "%";
                    }

                }

                function frameLeft() {
                    if (startPosition <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(intervalLeft);
                        intervalRight = setInterval(frameRight, 10);

                    } else {
                        startPosition -= 0.2;
                        document.getElementById("moveAnimation").style.left = startPosition + "%";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

this works how it Should. In the original code I posted the clearInterval was not linked to an actual intervalID